# Calculating intersection of two 3D vector polygons

Tags: qgis, gdal, intersection, 3d

I have not found a solution yet to intersect two 3d vector layers. The solution is to calculate the intersection of the two polygonal 3d surfaces.

Does anyone know a solution to intersect two vector layers?

As an example I attach the following example. The dashed line marked in yellow is to be calculated as the intersection line. I have not found the appropriate command lines for GDAL.

[image]

CSV Code for the first polygon:
[enter link description here](http://www.namotec.de/pub/ogr_check2dm_mesh_polz.pol)

```
1
4469855.780000 5507533.330000 2.149567
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 1.993225
4469856.750000 5507533.140000 1.998871
4469856.730000 5507533.430000 2.169739
4469855.780000 5507533.330000 2.149567
END
1
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 1.993225
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 1.944733
4469856.780000 5507532.930000 1.949158
4469856.750000 5507533.140000 1.998871
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 1.993225
END
1
4469856.780000 5507532.930000 1.949158
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 1.944733
4469855.880000 5507532.530000 2.085205
4469856.810000 5507532.620000 2.090668
4469856.780000 5507532.930000 1.949158
END
1
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 1.985687
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 1.993225
4469855.780000 5507533.330000 2.149567
4469854.800000 5507533.260000 2.181244
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 1.985687
END
1
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 1.985687
4469854.880000 5507532.760000 1.939545
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 1.944733
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 1.993225
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 1.985687
END
1
4469855.880000 5507532.530000 2.085205
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 1.944733
4469854.880000 5507532.760000 1.939545
4469854.930000 5507532.450000 2.074005
4469855.880000 5507532.530000 2.085205
END
END
```

CSV Code for the second polygon:
[enter link description here](http://www.namotec.de/pub/ogr_sol2net_wspmax_polz.pol)

```
1
4469855.780000 5507533.330000 2.061700
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 2.061700
4469856.750000 5507533.140000 2.056200
4469856.730000 5507533.430000 2.056200
4469855.780000 5507533.330000 2.061700
END
1
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 2.061700
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 2.061900
4469856.780000 5507532.930000 2.058100
4469856.750000 5507533.140000 2.056200
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 2.061700
END
1
4469856.780000 5507532.930000 2.058100
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 2.061900
4469855.880000 5507532.530000 2.061900
4469856.810000 5507532.620000 2.058100
4469856.780000 5507532.930000 2.058100
END
1
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 2.057300
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 2.061700
4469855.780000 5507533.330000 2.061700
4469854.800000 5507533.260000 2.057300
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 2.057300
END
1
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 2.057300
4469854.880000 5507532.760000 2.058000
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 2.061900
4469855.810000 5507533.060000 2.061700
4469854.850000 5507532.980000 2.057300
END
1
4469855.880000 5507532.530000 2.061900
4469855.840000 5507532.850000 2.061900
4469854.880000 5507532.760000 2.058000
4469854.930000 5507532.450000 2.058000
4469855.880000 5507532.530000 2.061900
END
END
```

With GDAL I can transform CSV code into a 3d shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -nlt POLYGON -dim 3 -overwrite   terrain_polz3d.shp   ogr_check2dm_mesh_polz.pol
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -nlt POLYGON -dim 3 -overwrite   water_polz3d.shp     ogr_sol2net_wspmax_polz.pol
```

Now how to calculate the intersection of the two polygons?

A solution with GDAL or QGIS3 is preferable.

Comment: That comma-less data format is not CSV, but Arc/Info GENERATE format.